# Помогите разобраться с EditText и клавиатурой, которая его выталкивает

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Всем привет. Такая проблема. Использую такую тему в приложении:

```
<style name="Theme.TransparencyDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

Есть TextView в верхней части экрана и EditText в нижней части экрана. нажимаю на EditText и открываю клавиатуру. EditText выталкивается клавиатурой вверх. это клево так я и хочу. но TextView который сверху уходит за пределы экрана. Этого я не хочу. Я пробовал засунуть весь контент который должен крутиться в  ScrollView но при выталкивании клавиатурой выталкивается сам  ScrollView а не прокручивается. В общем вот видео как сейчас работает: [видео](https://vk.com/video142681208_171151399)
Вот [видео из рабочего проэкта](https://vk.com/videos142681208?section=recoms&z=video142681208_171151324%2Fcb7d865114af6882db%2Fpl_updates)

Вопрос такой: как мне сделать, чтобы мой EditText  выталкивался клавиатурой, а остально верхний контент оставался на месте? или же как сделать padding  между EditText ом и клавиатурой когда  EditText выталкивается клавиатурой?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="1"
                android:background="#142e06" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:background="#ff4018"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ip696.com.skipwhite" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TransparencyDemo" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, поможет замена

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

в манифесте на

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```